# Unordered Queue/Stack

Tags: c#, collections, stack, queue

I want a data collection which I can take an element from, or add an element to, but which *doesn't* care or make promises about the ordering and it'll shout at me if I try to take more elements than it has?

Both `Queue<T>` and `Stack<T>` satisfy this, but they imply an ordering on the elements.

That's annoying because one of the other things I want to do is `RemoveWhere<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate)`.
With a `Queue<T>` or a `Stack<T>` I can easily implement a helper to do that, by removing items until I find a match, and then re-adding everything back.

But then I've got an object which asserts it maintains ordering but has broken that ordering :(

Naturally I can solve this with suitable MethodNames, or I could implement it all myself as a custom collection backed by a `List<T>`.

But before I reinvent the wheel ...

**Is there already a collection that satisfies my needs?**

Some sort of `Pile<T>` class?

Comment: Why not using `HashSet<T>`? It already has a `RemoveWhere` method.

Comment: For some reasons I thought you need multithreading, and then there is [ConcurrentBag<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1), but I am not aware about `Bag<T>` or something without concurency overhead.

Comment: The name of an unordered collection is a Bag.  As mentioned, .NET doesn't have a `Bag` class, you'd need to write one or use something that provides more functionality than a `Bag` would need to.

Comment: "Is there already a collection that satisfies my needs?" Well you've listed three that do right in  your question.  How do any of them not meet your needs?  You haven't specified in what way any of them are inadequate.

Comment: `But then I've got an object which asserts it maintains ordering but has broken that ordering :(`

Comment: If I use a `Queue` then I'd have to write an extension method on `Queue` which fundamentally broke how a `Queue` works. It would happen that I didn't care about it in my use case, some some other poor unsuspecting developer might end up using it when they DO care.

Comment: Is there a requirement for specific performance characteristics for the `RemoveWhere` operation? If you are OK with O(N), then creating a `Bag<T>` by wrapping a `List<T>` should be trivial.

Comment: No, this is test code, so simplicity of code is the highest goal. Self-implementing is fine, I was just checking that something like `Bag<T>` didn't already exist :)